# Can a conjunction "after" modify a noun in front of it?

Tags: conjunctions

I made the following sentence:

> This picture shows my face just after I waken up.

I would like to know whether the conjunction phrase "just after I waken up" can modify the noun "my face". My dictionaries say that a conjunction "when" can modify a noun, but say nothing regarding "after".

Comment: *Waken up* can't be used in any context I can think of. In every sentence I can envision, it would be a different verb form or phrase. (In the sentence in the question, it should be *after I **woke** up*, *after I **wake** up*, or *after I* ***awaken***.)

Comment: It it were me, I'd use "This picture shows my face just after waking up". I don't understand what the question is though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "after" can be used as a conjunction to introduce a clause. It can have either adverbal or adjectival function.

> I'm going to the party after I get dressed (adverbially, telling when I'm going to the party)

Or adjectivally as in "my face after I wake up".

Note that we use simple present in the clause, not "waken"